# How to Auto serving laravel

Tags: php, apache, localhost, local-network, laragon

is there any way to auto serving you laravel project?

i'm using virtual host.

`<VirtualHost *:80> #laragon magic!
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/pos/public/"
    ServerName apk.dev
    ServerAlias *.apk.dev
</VirtualHost>`

and to access it locally i open the Cmdr and write
`php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.100 --port 80`
every single time.

and i access it with other device with `192.168.1.100` it's working fine, i just want to know is there any way that i don't need to repeat it, and just by running the laragon i also can access the apk.dev from other device with my local network?

Comment: I think you could make a development environment for PHP using docker: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/docker-compose/3226/docker-compose-multi-container-example-with-default-network#t=201708141857056610701

Comment: i don't think it's a same case sir, or did i not get it?
i mean, i just want to host my apps on my PC for local network use. it's working fine with php artisan serve --host, but i must write it every time i restart the laragon / PC so i ask is there any way to make it auto start every time the laragon / PC start without typing php artisan serve --host in the Cmdr, by the way thanks sire

Comment: with docker-compose yo can use "restart: always" in your docker-compose-yml, so... every time you docker service restarts, your "restart: always" containers will up automatically too.

Comment: oh i see.. thanks a lot sire, i will try it..